# Finding leading 1s as well as column space in MxN matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

For $4\times 5$ matrix which is, 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 &-3 &4 &1 &0\\
0 & 6& 6 &1 &3\\
0 & 0& 0 &1 &9\\
0 & 0& 0& 0& 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I made it as RREF that is,

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    1& 3/2 &5 &1 &0\\
    0 &1& 1& 1/6& 1/2\\
    0 &0& 0& 1& 9\\
    0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
I know the first column is the basis for the column space, but I do not understand why the second and fourth columns are also basis for the column space... isn`t leading 1 representing a column that has only one value that is 1? Please help...

Comment: You are clearly very confused about the meaning of “basis”. What makes you think that “the first column is the basis for the column space”? What does that even *mean*?

Comment: You found row echelon form, but it's not reduced. Matrix is in RREF iff it's in row echelon form, pivots (first nonzero entry in a row) are all 1 and each pivot is the only nonzero term in a column